# Waiting for a JFrame and then retrieving information from it

Tags: java, swing, jframe

First of all I'm new to Java and you'll probably be able to guess. Thanks in advance.

I'm currently writing a board game using Java for an assignment. There are human and computer player classes, and the GUI only in the human player class. In the human class I use a class called 'UI' extending JFrame where the user selects a piece.

At the moment this UI class waits for the enter button to be pressed then sets a 'done' variable to true. In the human player class I create this UI then wait in a while loop continuously checking this boolean before getting the X/Y position of the move.

```
while (!input.moveEntered());
move.setPosition(input.getX(), input.getY());
```

This only seems to work if the while loop is not empty. If I add a print statement in there it works fine. 
It seems like there is a much better way to go about this. I've looked into dialogs but I don't close the window every time a move is entered.

Thanks for reading.

Comment: GUI's are event driven, maybe you should consider using an [Observer Pattern](http://www.oodesign.com/observer-pattern.html) instead, this will allow you to free the GUI thread to update the UI. You might also consider having a look at [Concurrency in Java](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/)

Answer (score 2):

You should never be busy-waiting; in your case, I would show a modal JDialog.  When the user has entered their input, the setVisible(true) method will end without busy-waiting.

Or maybe I misunderstood your problem and you only need to define an event listener in your main JFrame in order to handle user input.  Have a look at
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/swing/swing_event_listeners.htm

Comment: Plus one for everything before *"Or maybe.."*. A modal dialog is the way to go here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help. JDialogs work but ideally I'd like the window to stay open after the user has pressed enter. I think I didn't explain myself very well. Basically, this JFrame/Dialog is launched from the main thread and shows the (initially empty) board to the user, who then moves a cursor over his desired position and presses enter. I'm not sure how to wait for the user to actually make his selection without waiting in a loop or using JDialogs (which makes the window close and immediately reopen after the computer makes it's choice)