# Stop JDialog blocking without closing

Tags: java, swing, jdialog

I'm currently doing an assignment which involves implementing some board game in Java. We have to work around the interfaces the lecturer has given us. The actual 'UI' class is separate from the game logic and is launched in the main thread. Originally this class extended JFrame. When the user pressed enter, a boolean was set to show that he/she has made their move, and the main thread waited in a while loop repeatedly polled the JFrame to see if the user has made his move:

```
while (!input.moveEntered())
{
    //sleep for 100ms
}
move.setPosition(input.getX(), input.getY());
return move;
```

This was very obviously not the way to go about it, and thanks to some help I got from a previous question ([Waiting for a JFrame and then retrieving information from it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36419330/waiting-for-a-jframe-and-then-retrieving-information-from-it)) I started using a modal JDialog. The fact that setVisible() blocks is good, however it seems that JDialogs are for single inputs. Is there any way to stop blocking the main thread without ending the setVisible method and closing the window? I need the window to stay open in-between moves:

[image: Please stop flashing]
Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's hard to tell, but it just sounds like you're entire thought process is wrong. Each time the user makes a move, you should be checking for a win condition, when it occurs you can trigger a new event for some other observer/controller to deal with, no need for a modal dialog.  And yes, you `while-loop` freaks me out completely

Comment: Thats how I would do it but we must implement the interfaces we're given. We have a game manager that has two instances of players (can be computer/human) and it calls on them to return a move. The human player launches a UI to get the move and return it, and then after the moves are made the win condition is checked